# How do dict2.setdefault() work ? How it influence my if else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, setdefault

```
dict2 = {'Name': 'sandeep', 'Age': 15, 'Class': '11th', 'school': 'GSBV'}
print(dict2)
if 'collage' in dict2.keys(): print(dict2['collage'])
else: print('no key found in dict')
print(dict2.setdefault('collage', 'this key do not exist in dict'))
if 'collage' in dict2.keys(): print(dict2['collage'])
else: print('no key found in dict')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
no key found in dict
this key do not exist in dict
this key do not exist in dict
```

It does not print

> no key found in dict

but instead, it prints

> this key do not exist in dict

in the last line, why is my program having this behavior?

Comment: this code works correctly, What do you expect? when use `setdefault` if the key doesn't exist add a key with the default value and in the second if `college` exist in the dict and doesn't print : `no key found in dict`

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) make it pretty clear what `dict.setdefault` does. Did you read the documentation? That should be the first place you look when you have any questions about a function

Comment: [If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Comment: You can use `print(dict2)` after `dict2.setdefault` and see what exist in `dict2`

Comment: don't put code after `:` but in next line - your code is unreadable. See more: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

`setdefault` is exactly what it sounds like.  It sets the default value for a key in the dictionary.  The first parameter given to the method is the `key` you want to set, and the second parameter is the default value. So when you run `setdefault` on a `dict` that already has a value for the key, it simply ignores it.  Otherwise it will set the key to the default value.

For example:

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> a.setdefault('key', 'value')
'value'
>>> a.setdefault('key', 'othervalue')
'value'
>>> a
{'key': 'value'}
```

As you can see when the `dict` was empty calling `setdefault` added the key, value pair and returned the value, but when called again it didn't change the `value` to `othervalue` because a value already existed.

This is convenient especially when you are dealing with iterable types.

For example:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> for char in ["A", "B", "C"]:
...     for num in [1, 2, 3]:
...         lst = a.setdefault(char, [])
...         lst.append(num)
...
>>> a
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Without `setdefault` It would be neccessary to write a conditional statement that checked on every iteration if the key had already been set or not.